# I get a 404 error in web.py when using /(.+) (Newbie Q)

Tags: web.py

here is my code and my issue.

```
import web

render = web.template.render('templates/')

urls = (
    '/(.+)', 'index'
)

class index:
        def GET(self, lang):
            return render.index(lang)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

and my index.html is this one:

```
$def with (lang)


$if lang == 'en':
    I just wanted to say <em>hello</em>
$elif lang =='es' or lang == '':
    <em>Hola</em>, mundo!
$else:
    página no disponible en este idioma
```

the problem is that when I run this code I get an 404 error. I think the issue might be the urls part, specifically the /(.+). I think I'm not using it right, and I wanna make it work so I can use more than one parameter. When I use /(.*) it work, but not for more than one parameters, and the doc says that for more than 1 parameter I gotta use + instead of *

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should study regexp, webpy only matches it against path and passes matched groups to controller method. You can mark group as optional with `?` so if it is empty then it is not captured and lang will be set to None by default.

Also `.` in regexp means any symbol, to capture language you'd better use `\w` that matches any word character.

```
urls = (
    '/(\w+)?', 'index'
)

class index:
    def GET(self, lang=None):
        return render.index(lang)
```